# upgrading from 2.1 to 2.3

Tags: auto-updates

The project I was working on was put on hold a few months back. Back then I was on version 2.1.2570. Now the project is back on. After having gone through the pain of manually restoring the InnoDB tablespaces because I switched development systems in the meanwhile and didn't bother to do a proper mysqldump, I'm now facing the task of upgrading Craft from 2.1.2570 to the latest revision. It fails while updating the database. Is there any place where I can download older releases (i.e. 2.2.2579) to see if they come through?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, have a look at the Craft site for details about downloading a specifc build of Craft:

http://buildwithcraft.com/help/download-previous-versions

So if you want to download 2.2.2579, the URL will be:

http://download.buildwithcraft.com/craft/2.2/2.2.2579/Craft-2.2.2579.zip